# ajax image from asp.net webservice

Tags: asp.net, ajax, charts

I am trying to build an image of a chart using an AJAX call to a Webservice. I am able to build the chart and convert it into an image but for some reason I cannot get the image back to my AJAX call.

The asp.net web service method that looks like this.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public void getCandles(string Symbol)
    {            
        Chart chrt = new Chart();

        stockQuotes.bldChart(ref chrt); //// returns chart of candlesticks

        bytes[] chartBytes;

        using (var chartimage = new MemoryStream())  //// change chart to bytes
            {
                try
                {
                    chrt.SaveImage(chartimage, ChartImageFormat.Png);
                    chartBytes = chartimage.GetBuffer();
                }catch
                {
                    return (null);
                }
            }

         /// Transform to memory stream and finally to image
         MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(chartImage);
         Image img = Image.FromStream(ms)


        /// Build respoonse                         
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        index._Stocks[Symbol].ChartImage.Save(Context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);            

    }
```

This method is invoked by an AJAX call that looks as follows:

```
 function UpdatePriceChart()
    {
        var selectedSymbol = $("#ddlSymbols").val();



        $.ajax({
            url: "/WS/wsCandles.asmx/getCandles",
            data: { "Symbol": $("#ddlSymbols").val() },
            method: "post",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#chrtPrice').attr('src', data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }

        })
    }
```

For some reason, the image returned is always empty. Can anyone steer me in the right direction. Thank you for your help.

Comment: set the dataType as `image/png` in jQuery ajax call. And also make it a GEt request type rather than POST.

Comment: The data you send is a full image binary format, you place it on the src of an img that ask for a file name, or embedding base64 image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case like that, I usually go with a handler that returns the image back direct to the src of the `img`, for example, the page part will be something like:

```
function UpdatePriceChart()
    {
        var selectedSymbol = $("#ddlSymbols").val();

        $('#chrtPrice').attr('src', '/WS/wsCandles.ashx?symbol=' + selectedSymbol);
    }
```

and the handler will be something like:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext Context) 
{
        Chart chrt = new Chart();
        stockQuotes.bldChart(ref chrt); //// returns chart of candlesticks

        bytes[] chartBytes;

        using (var chartimage = new MemoryStream())  //// change chart to bytes
            {
                try
                {
                    chrt.SaveImage(chartimage, ChartImageFormat.Png);
                    chartBytes = chartimage.GetBuffer();
                }catch
                {
                    return (null);
                }
            }

         /// Transform to memory stream and finally to image
         MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(chartImage);
         Image img = Image.FromStream(ms)


        /// Build respoonse                         
        Context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        index._Stocks[Symbol].ChartImage.Save(Context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);            
}
```

You need to add some extra code to read the symbol, and maybe some extra changes to work as expect, but this is the idea.